# orthogonal chebyshev polyhomials

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This Theorem says

statement:
 $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{T_n(x)T_m(x)}{ \sqrt{1+x^2} } dx = 0 ;$ when $n\ne m $

proof:
"substitute $x= cos \theta$ " 
and that's it.

So I am wondering should I start with this

$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{cos(\theta n)cos(\theta m)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} dx $
or with this

$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{cos(\theta n)cos(\theta m)}{\sqrt{1+cos^2 \theta}} dx $
I order to verify the proof.

note: T(x) is Chebyshev polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this, you apply the substitution rule for integrals, fully. Everything with $x$ in it, including the denominator, the $dx$, and the limits, transform.

On the other hand, the statement that you're trying to prove is incorrect. The correct form has $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ in the denominator instead.

Comment: $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{cos(\theta n)cos(\theta m)}{\sqrt{1+cos^2 \theta}} dx =   \int_{0}^{\pi} cos(\theta m). cos(\theta n) d\theta$
I wonder how this come about when we change $x$ to $cos(\theta)$ where does the denominator go.

Comment: It goes into the $d\theta$. Well, it does if you use the correct version with a minus sign in that square root.

Comment: I see, trig substitutions.